# How to append and remove data while particular selected radio buttons are selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement

Hello I'm trying to append the data and remove the data on the basis of which radio button is selected but in my case any button I selected thats data will append to the div Can you please solve the problem that how to add and remove the data according to the selected radio button.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {    
        $(".paymethod").on("click", function(){
            paymentMethod = $(this).val();
            switch(paymentMethod){
                case "stripe":
                $(".stripe_fields").append("stripe appended text.");
                break;
                case "square":
                $(".square_fields").append("Square appended text.");
                break;
                case "authorize.net":
                $(".authorize.net_fields").append("Authorize appended text.");
                break;
                case "paypal":
                $(".paypal_fields").append("Paypal appended text.");
                break;
                default:
                alert("select a payment method");
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
  label{
                display: inline-block;
            }
            label:hover{
                cursor:pointer;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" class="paymethod" name="radio" value="square">square
                <div class="square_fields"></div>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" class="paymethod" name="radio" value="stripe">stripe
                <div class="stripe_fields"></div>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" class="paymethod" name="radio" value="authorize.net">authorize.net
                <div class="authorize.net_fields"></div>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" class="paymethod" name="radio" value="paypal">paypal
                <div class="paypal_fields"></div>
            </label>
        </form>
```

Comment: use change event instead of click

Comment: @BearNithi I changed it but not working

Comment: remove icon id 
$('#your id').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    
});

Comment: @Ragupathi I'm not getting what you are saying

Comment: you mean if you've previously selected `square` and now you select `stripe`, you want to replace `Square appended text` with `stripe appended text`???

Comment: @Elish yes I want to do that thing

Comment: Replace `append` with `html`

Comment: @Elish in html can I pass the elements of the html?

Comment: yes you can. `html()` accepts string of html.

Comment: @Elish using html existing text in not remove :(

Comment: @catter try my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sory I misunderstood your requiresments in the comment section. But still you can use `html()` to clear the all `label.div` you want.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {    
        $(".paymethod").on("click", function(){
            paymentMethod = $(this).val();
$(this).parent().siblings('label').children('div').html('');
            switch(paymentMethod){
                case "stripe":
                $(".stripe_fields").append("stripe appended text.");
                break;
                case "square":
                $(".square_fields").append("Square appended text.");
                break;
                case "authorize.net":
                $(".authorize_net_fields").append("Authorize appended text.");
                break;
                case "paypal":
                $(".paypal_fields").append("Paypal appended text.");
                break;
                default:
                alert("select a payment method");
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
  label{
                display: inline-block;
            }
            label:hover{
                cursor:pointer;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" class="paymethod" name="radio" value="square">square
                <div class="square_fields"></div>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" class="paymethod" name="radio" value="stripe">stripe
                <div class="stripe_fields"></div>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" class="paymethod" name="radio" value="authorize.net">authorize.net
                <div class="authorize_net_fields"></div>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" class="paymethod" name="radio" value="paypal">paypal
                <div class="paypal_fields"></div>
            </label>
        </form>
```

Also note that you've used **authorized.net** as class for the `div` inside your third `lable`. if you pass this **authorized.net** to jquery selector `$` as `$(".authorize.net_fields")` it will search for elements with the classes `authorize` and `net_fields` *for eg(`<div class="authorize net_fields"></div>`)*. So you can set the class attribute for the `div` inside your third `label` as **`authorize_net_fields`** not **`authorize.net_fields`**

Answer (score 0):

Your switch case should be like this. It should remove the values from other div.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.paymethod').on('click', function() {
    paymentMethod = $(this).val();
    switch (paymentMethod) {
      case 'stripe':
        $('.stripe_fields').html('stripe appended text.');
        $('.square_fields').html('');
        $('.authorize').html('');
        $('.paypal_fields').html('');
        break;
      case 'square':
        $('.square_fields').html('Square appended text.');
        $('.stripe_fields').html('');
        $('.authorize').html('');
        $('.paypal_fields').html('');
        break;
      case 'authorize.net':
        $('.authorize.net_fields').html('Authorize appended text.');
        $('.stripe_fields').html('');
        $('.square_fields').html('');
        $('.paypal_fields').html('');
        break;
      case 'paypal':
        $('.paypal_fields').html('Paypal appended text.');
        $('.stripe_fields').html('');
        $('.square_fields').html('');
        $('.authorize').html('');
        break;
      default:
        alert('select a payment method');
    }
  });
});
```

I have updated all the case, based on your radio buttons you should remove other values from the div.

Answer (score 0):

try this,its working fine for me you have to remove all content before you append new one

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".paymethod").on("click", function () {
            paymentMethod = $(this).val();
            RemoveOthers();
            switch (paymentMethod) {
                case "stripe":
                    $(".stripe_fields").append("stripe appended text.");
                    break;
                case "square":
                    $(".square_fields").append("Square appended text.");
                    break;
                case "authorize.net":
                    $(".authorize_net_fields").append("Authorize appended text.");
                    break;
                case "paypal":
                    $(".paypal_fields").append("Paypal appended text.");
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("select a payment method");
            }
        });
});
    function RemoveOthers(){
        $(".stripe_fields").empty();
        $(".square_fields").empty();
        $(".authorize_net_fields").empty();
        $(".paypal_fields").empty();

    }
```

html

```
 <div class="authorize_net_fields"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.paymethod').on('change',function (){
        paymentMethod = $(this).val();
        $("form div").html("");
        $(this).siblings().html(paymentMethod + " appended text.");
    });
});
```